# Is there any way to access a sub-type method without casting using generic

Tags: java

To access sub-class method down-casting is needed, is there is a way to achieve this using generic without type-casting in same manner.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Animal parrot = new Bird();
        ((Bird)parrot).fly();
    }
}

interface Animal{
    void eat();
}
class Bird implements Animal{
    @Override
    public void eat() {}
    public void fly(){}
}
```

Comment: You could just declare `Bird parrot = new Bird();`?

Comment: I'm not seeing how generics would apply here...?

Comment: If you want it to fly then it's not an animal. You meant to have a bird from the beginning.

Comment: There are no generics here. This is simply casting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please note that SO is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer!), please *stick around* so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Animal parrot = new Bird();
        parrot.move();
    }
}

interface Animal{
    void eat();
    void move();

}
class Bird implements Animal{
    @Override
    public void eat() {}
    public void move(){fly();}
    public void fly(){}
}
```

It could work with something like this I guess

Interfaces are meant to add methods to implemented classes without defining actual code for this method, meaning that any implemented class will definitely have the same methods but 2 implemented methods with the same name won't necessarily perform the same action.

To explain it with the current thread it would be:

```
interface Animal {
    void move();
}

class Bird implements Animal{
    public void move(){
        fly();
    }
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    public void move(){
        walk();
    }
}
```

This way, each class will have its own definition of the move method while in `main` each method will be called by `object.move()`.

This way of doing things allows to go from a code like this

```
for (object tmp:objList){
   if(tmp.class=="Bird")
      tmp.fly();
   }
   else if (tmp.class=="Dog"){
      tmp.walk();
   }
...
}
```

to

```
for (object tmp:objList){
    tmp.move();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The parrot class should extend the Bird class, then you can call the fly method from a parrot object directly and without need to cast.

```
public class Parrot extends Bird{

//have some filed or method

}
```

Comment: What's the point? It would work even if `parrot` was declared as a `Bird` and not as an `Animal`, even if it is not a separate class.

Comment: yes, it could be. but there is no way to have an animal referenced object with the fly method.

Comment: Then the answer should be "don't use `Animal`, use `Bird`". Declaring a `Parrot` class doesn't help in any way.